# How to create a boolean column that collectively responds to another column based on an ID column (using dplyr)?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to create a table from this:

| ID | Condition |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | B |

To this:

| ID | Condition | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 1 |
| 1 | B | 1 |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | 0 |
| 2 | B | 0 |

i.e. If the condition is A within any rows of the same ID, the flag would return 1 for all rows of the same ID.

I have tried something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(Flag = ifelse(Condition == 1, 1, 0)
```

But it just returns this:

| ID | Condition | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 0 |
| 1 | B | 0 |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | 0 |
| 2 | B | 0 |

Sorry if this is unclear, if there is anything else you need from me for this question please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ifelse` is element-wise `if-else` statement, say, vectorized, which cannot give the desired output.

You can use `if ... else ...` instead of `ifelse`

```
> df %>% mutate(Flag = if (any(Condition == "A")) 1 else 0, .by = ID)
  ID Condition Flag
1  1         B    1
2  1         B    1
3  1         A    1
4  2         B    0
5  2         B    0
```

Or you can try `%in%`

```
> df %>% mutate(Flag = +("A" %in% Condition), .by = ID)
  ID Condition Flag
1  1         B    1
2  1         B    1
3  1         A    1
4  2         B    0
5  2         B    0
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your `Flag` column is essentially logical, you can use `any` to test whether there's "A" per (`.by`) ID.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Flag = as.integer(any(Condition == "A")), .by = ID)

  ID Condition Flag
1  1         B    1
2  1         B    1
3  1         A    1
4  2         B    0
5  2         B    0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could think of this as a two-part operation. First, identify the universe of IDs that meet the condition, which you can do via subsetting:

```
data$ID[grep("A", data$Condition)]
```

Next use an `%in%` operator to find all observations that have one of the IDs you identified.

```
data$ID %in% data$ID[grep("A", data$Condition)
```

Then all that's left to do is assign your `flag` variable, which you can again do by subsetting. Putting it together, this is the full line:

```
data$Flag[data$ID %in% data$ID[grep("A", data$Condition)]] <- 1
```